# JS: Sum column values and updating result on change

Tags: javascript

I have a table where, for each row, I must show the sum of two columns and present it in a third one. The sum must be calculated everytime any of the inputs change.

- Each row has an unique id.
- Each column input field has it's own name (altough the name repeats for each row)

This is the structure of the table with sample data:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Element Name ABC</td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div><input id="SM-J3D-01-1" onkeyup="calc(this);" onchange="calc(this);" type="number" min="0" step="1" name="Validos" class="form-control" value="0" />
                 <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Validos" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
            </div>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div><input id="SM-J3D-01-1" onkeyup="calc(this);" onchange="calc(this);" type="number" min="0" step="1" name="Cortesia" class="form-control" value="0" />
                 <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Cortesia" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
             </div>
             </div>
         </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div><input id="SM-J3D-01-1" type="number" readonly name="Total" class="form-control" value="0" />
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Total" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    //Begining second row    
    <tr>
        <td>Element Name XYZ</td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div><input id="SM-J3D-01-2" onkeyup="calc(this);" onchange="calc(this);" type="number" min="0" step="1" name="Validos" class="form-control" value="0" />
                 <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Validos" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
             </div>
             </div>
         </td>
         <td>
             <div class="form-group">
             <div><input id="SM-J3D-01-2" onkeyup="calc(this);" onchange="calc(this);" type="number" min="0" step="1" name="Cortesia" class="form-control" value="0" />
                  <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Cortesia" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
              </div>
              </div>
          </td>
          <td>
              <div class="form-group">
              <div><input id="SM-J3D-01-2" type="number" readonly name="Total" class="form-control" value="0" />
                   <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Total" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
               </div>
               </div>
           </td>
```

I'm starting to study Javascript but this goes beyond I know at the moment. So far I tried something I saw online but no luck. If you have a better proposal feel free to post it. I'll try to understand it and put it in practice.

JS:

```
    $(function calc(id) {
        var row = id.parentNode.parentNode;
        var validos = row.cells[6].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
        var cortesia = row.cells[7].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

        resultado = parseFloat(validos) + parseFloat(cortesia);

        row.cells[10].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = resultado;
    });
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Are you using jQuery in this? If so, it can probably be heavily simplified. I see you using `$()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code.
Add for each input (which the value gonna be taken from) this class for example:
`toBeCalced`, and for each input which the total will be showed in, this class for example `total`.
In JS we gonna use JQuery to listen to `change` event, and do these steps:

- go to parent row.
- iterate over each children with class `toBeCalced` and add its value to `total` variable.
- Get the total input by class name `total` and set the total value.

We get this result:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toBeCalced').change(function() {
      var row = $(this).closest('tr');
      var valuesToSum = row.find('.toBeCalced');
      var total = 0;
      $.each(valuesToSum, function(index, item) {
        total += parseInt($(item).val());
      });

      var totalInput = row.find('.total')[0];
      $(totalInput).val(total);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>Element Name ABC</td>
      <td>
          <div class="form-group">
          <div><input id="SM-J3D-01-1" type="number" min="0" step="1" name="Validos" class="toBeCalced form-control" value="0" />
               <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Validos" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
          </div>
          </div>
      </td>
      <td>
          <div class="form-group">
          <div><input id="SM-J3D-01-1" type="number" min="0" step="1" name="Cortesia" class="toBeCalced form-control" value="0" />
               <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Cortesia" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
           </div>
           </div>
       </td>
      <td>
          <div class="form-group">
          <div><input id="SM-J3D-01-1" type="number" readonly name="Total" class="total form-control" value="0" />
          <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Total" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
          </div>
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
  //Begining second row    
  <tr>
      <td>Element Name XYZ</td>
      <td>
          <div class="form-group">
          <div><input id="SM-J3D-01-2" type="number" min="0" step="1" name="Validos" class="toBeCalced form-control" value="0" />
               <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Validos" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
           </div>
           </div>
       </td>
       <td>
           <div class="form-group">
           <div><input id="SM-J3D-01-2" type="number" min="0" step="1" name="Cortesia" class="toBeCalced form-control" value="0" />
                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Cortesia" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div><input id="SM-J3D-01-2" type="number" readonly name="Total" class="total form-control" value="0" />
                 <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Total" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
             </div>
             </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works really well and this will be a good foundation for another situations similar to this :)

Comment: In case you want to take a look to the part 2 :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050298/jquery-aritmetic-operations-using-column-values-and-update-on-change